# SQL Server 2008 - Update system catalog from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

We had some old stored procedures in SQL Server 2000 which updated system catalog from an application which was used for user application security which is tied to SQL Server roles to take advantage of SQL Server in-built security and NT logins.

When we migrate DB to SQL Server 2008 and try to run these stored procedure we get SQL Server 2008 error

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

I searched around and found that from SQL Server 2005 onwards MS do not support catalog updates (unless using Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC) ).

If anyone can help me with how to do this in new versions or any other alternative (like .Net code run in Sql server??) that will be great.

Some sample queries below

```
update sysusers 
set roles = convert(varbinary(2048), substring(convert(binary(2048), roles), 1, @ruidbyte-1)
            + convert(binary(1), (~@ruidbit) & substring(convert(binary(2048), roles), @ruidbyte, 1)) 
            + substring(convert(binary(2048), roles), @ruidbyte+1, 2048-@ruidbyte)), 
   updatedate = getdate()
where uid = @memuid

delete from syspermissions where grantee = @uid

delete from sysusers where uid = @uid

insert into sysusers 
values(@uid, 0, @rolename, NULL, 0x00, getdate(), getdate(), @owner, NULL)
```

Comment: Basically, those system catalog **views** (in SQL Server 2005/2008 and newer) are just that - read-only views into system tables. Those system tables aren't editable by regular code - neither T-SQL nor SQL-CLR. You need to use "official", published API's like `CREATE USER` or `DROP USER` to do such operations - the system catalog views will update automatically when you do this

Comment: Agreed with @marc_s - please use documented and supported methods to implement security.

Answer (score 1):

There is no routine reason to update system tables in SQL Server. Ever.

There is a whole array of commands and system stored procedures to do it properly in all versions of SQL Server.

You can't anyway as you noted: there is no hack or workaround

Comment: Thank you for the details. What will be some equivalemnt system stored procedures to do the following                                           delete from syspermissions where grantee = #uid

delete from sysusers where uid = #uid

insert into sysusers 
values(#uid, 0, #rolename, NULL, 0x00, getdate(), getdate(), #owner, NULL)

Comment: DROP USER and CREATE USER (just search). Dropping user remove permissions too

Comment: The reason for not using the sp_addrolemember system stored procedures where to allow non-dbo_ users to safely access and execute a revised copy of sp_addrolemember . Does that restriction still exists in SQL 2008?

Comment: If you wrap sp_addrolemember in another stored proc, you can use EXECUTE AS OWNER (I assume dbo) to escalate rights for the proc scope to do all your actions needed. This is new in SQL server 2005+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Updating a system table can be a **dangerous task**, as it may lead to unexpected results. So before you do that just make sure that you are very confident with whatever you are doing. It would be advisable that you do the changes on a replica of the original database to prevent unwanted results or crashes in the database.

The possible ways could be:

1. Use a **DAC**. You can get the technique after searching it on google. It is more of hacking the system tables.
2. Use the following code:

sp_configure 'allow updates',1
go

//your code

reconfigure with override
go

reconfigure would configure back your database. 
setting '**allow updates**' to '1' would allow you to update the system tables.

But the best way would be to find an another alternative for your task.!